# Skobbler iOS SDK: Why are there borders around my map annotations?

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

Creating an iOS mapping app using Skobbler's SDK *(installed via CocoaPods. v2.5)*. I'm adding annotations to my Skobbler mapview, using custom views for my pins instead of using one of Skobbler's defaults. My pins will just be colored circles.

The problem is that my circles seem to be drawn with borders, but they shouldn't be.

[image: portion of screen capture from iPhone]

My code is similar to the following:

```
let pin = UIView()  
pin.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18)
pin.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
pin.layer.cornerRadius = diameter/2

//Just for good measure... NO BORDER
pin.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
pin.layer.borderWidth = 0

let annotation = SKAnnotation()
annotation.annotationView = SKAnnotationView(view: pin, reuseIdentifier: "viewID")
annotation.identifier = 1234
annotation.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.1234, -111.1234)
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, withAnimationSettings: animationSettings)
```

How can I avoid having borders drawn around my pins?

Comment: Try to set a small border that has the same color as your pin has (lightGrayColor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that a light border is added by the framework, and I'm told there is nothing I can do.

Here's a snippet from an email from Skobbler:

> "Indeed we can see a light border (see attach)- that’s the way is
>   generated at our core level and we cannot change this. We’ve checked
>   also if we set a simple view on the map and if we add that view to an
>   annotation indeed the border appears (screenshot 2)."